# How much data can be serialized by Django

Tags: django, database, serialization, data-structures, django-rest-framework

For instance i have millions of users and i want to serialize all users data and return it when client requests, so client can get list of all users.

Also is this a  is a good approach? performance wise.

Comment: Serializing a million users at once, not a good idea. It will be very slow. Let's say it takes 1 sec to serialize 10000 records. That's 1 min 40 sec for   a million records. But that also depends on what kind of fields/data you're serializing. Leaving that aside, you will also run out of RAM. If one record = 1 KB so a million records = 1 GB. If you're running, say 4 processes of your Django app, that's 4 GB.

Comment: A better approach would be to serialize data in "pages". So if a client requests first page, you give them first thousand users. If the client requests second page, you give them the next thousand users.

Comment: Thanks for insight, yeah good idea, that's pretty much what i'm going to do after knowing the time and space that's gonna take to serialize all users at once.